# Flutter deep links open in web browser instead of app

Tags: flutter, android-deep-link, flutter-go-router, flutter-deep-link

I'm using go_router to handle all of my routes and navigation in my flutter app

This is my router defined

```
static GoRouter router =  GoRouter(
    navigatorKey: StateService.navigatorKey,
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: StartPage.id,
        builder: (context, state) => const StartPage(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: FirstPage.id,
        builder: (context, state) => const FirstPage(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: SecondPage.id,
        builder: (context, state) => const SecondPage(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: ThirdPage.id,
        builder: (context, state) => const ThirdPage(),
      ),
    ],
  );
```

I've also set up deep linking in my manifest.xml file as follows :

```
<meta-data
                android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled"
                android:value="true" />

            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="link-tester-flutter.web.app"
                    android:pathPattern="/*" />
                <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="link-tester-flutter.web.app"
                    android:pathPattern="/*" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

The problem is that my deep link does not open inside my app. It always opens in the browser.

I tried two different testing scenarios first I tested my deep link in the simulator using the following command

```
adb shell 'am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW \                                             
    -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE \
    -d "https://link-tester-flutter.web.app/second-page"' \
    com.example.dynamic_links
```

I then disabled/uninstalled my web browser on my android device and that way whenever I open url it opens it inside the app. I am very close to making this work as my links are indeed working. what am I doing wrong here? why do they always open in browser and not in the app?

**Note : A flutter web version of this app has been hosted on firebase and I have indeed included the assetlinks.json file.**